# How to run github action job after all conditional jobs, even it's didn't ran?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to create a GitHub Action with some conditional jobs. I want to run these conditional jobs paralell, but after all finished I want to continue with another job what needs to wait finish all conditional jobs.

This is my workflow what I want to implement:

1. Detect file changes in template folders
2. Run `npm run prod` in every template folder what changed
3. Wait until all template build finished
4. Coninue the deploy process

Here is my `deploy.yml` file:

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - deploy

jobs:
  check-theme-changes:
    name: Check template changes
    outputs:
      run_job: ${{ steps.check_files.outputs.run_job }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2

      - name: check modified files
        id: check_files
        run: |
          echo "=============== list modified files ==============="
          git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD
          
          echo "========== check paths of modified files =========="
          git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD > files.txt
          while IFS= read -r file
          do
            echo $file
            if [[ $file != laravel/resources/themes/project_a/* ]]; then
              echo "::set-output name=run_project_a_build::false"
              break
            else
              echo "::set-output name=run_project_a_build::true"
              break
            fi
          done < files.txt
            
          while IFS= read -r file
          do
            if [[ $file != laravel/resources/themes/project_b/* ]]; then
              echo "::set-output name=run_project_b_build::false"
              break
            else
              echo "::set-output name=run_project_b_build::true"
              break
            fi
          done < files.txt

  build-theme-project-a:
    name: Build project_a theme
    needs: check-theme-changes
    if: needs.check-theme-changes.outputs.run_project_a_build == 'true'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Read current version
      id: CURRENT
      run: echo "::set-output name=VERSION::$(cat /var/www/latest)"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        cd /var/www/${{steps.CURRENT.outputs.VERSION}}/laravel
        npm ci
    - name: npm run prod --theme=project_a
      run: |
        cd /var/www/${{steps.CURRENT.outputs.VERSION}}/laravel
        npm run prod --theme=project_a
    - name: Publish build
      run: # some git command here

  build-theme-project-b:
    name: Build project_b theme
    needs: check-theme-changes
    if: needs.check-theme-changes.outputs.run_project_b_build == 'true'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Read current version
      id: CURRENT
      run: echo "::set-output name=VERSION::$(cat /var/www/latest)"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        cd /var/www/${{steps.CURRENT.outputs.VERSION}}/laravel
        npm ci
    - name: npm run prod --theme=project_b
      run: |
        cd /var/www/${{steps.CURRENT.outputs.VERSION}}/laravel
        npm run prod --theme=project_b
    - name: Publish build
      run: # some git command here

  prepare:
    name: Prepare to clone a new version
    needs: [
      build,
      build-theme-project-a,
      build-theme-project-b
    ]
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - name: Save current date
      run: echo "$(date +'%s')" > /var/www/latest
```

The problem is if a theme isn't changed the variable will be `false` and then the `prepare` job's need will also skip the proceduring and all next step too, because they expect previous job finish.

How can I run job after a skipped step, but wait for it to finish?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is to use:

```
if: always()
```

on your `prepare` job.

You can then combine it with checking results, like this:

```
prepare:
    name: Prepare to clone a new version
    needs: [
       build,
       build-theme-project-a,
       build-theme-project-b
    ]
    if: ${{ always() && !cancelled() && needs.build.result == 'success' }}
```

To avoid running it in case job was cancelled.

Comment: It might also be helpful to check for _any_ failures across upstream jobs:
`if: always() && !cancelled() && !contains(needs.*.result, 'failure')`  Also, in recent versions of GitHub, you may omit `${{` and `}}` around the condition.

Comment: @CraigAustin oh needs.*.result is interesting one, I didn't know you can do it - thanks for sharing

Comment: BTW the following (run if _any_ dependency success) doesn't seem to work: `always() && !cancelled() && contains(needs.*.result, 'success')`